# Is there any way to send an HTTP "GET" request and include cookie(s) in the URL?

Tags: html, url, cookies, get

I'd like an easy way to send a GET request and included cookie info in the URL.  I could probably cobble together a request in Chrome debugger -- I'm just looking for a quick and dirty way to do it while trying to figure out how a COTS product behaves.

I've tried:
https://myserver.nowhere.com/mashupmgr/hapi/processApps?_=1667155192621&2alfssolX1X-2095811475X1=5b2ca93f4ad010a9a0069bc478127304c5000a97&JSESSIONID=E3E2EB8D03AF77E9037E784BFA87B57B

and a JSON-ish style

[https://myserver.nowhere.com/mashupmgr/hapi/processApps?_=1667155192621&cookie{"2alfssolX1X-2095811475X1":"5b2ca93f4ad010a9a0069bc478127304c5000a97",JSESSIONID:"E3E2EB8D03AF77E9037E784BFA87B57B"}](https://myserver.nowhere.com/mashupmgr/hapi/processApps?_=1667155192621&cookie%7B%222alfssolX1X-2095811475X1%22:%225b2ca93f4ad010a9a0069bc478127304c5000a97%22,JSESSIONID:%22E3E2EB8D03AF77E9037E784BFA87B57B%22%7D)

Neither work.